# Is there any relation between charging rate and discharging rate?

Tags: battery, charging

Sometimes when I do not use the  original charger but a different one it would take less time to fully charge the device than the original charger would do. But I can feel that discharging rate is higher after using these chargers.

Is it true?  If it is true, then what is the actual reason?

Comment: I deleted my answer because it's not convinced me after reading it post many years. Will post when I get better evidence

Comment: I have similar experiences.  I can tell which charger I used based on the discharge rate.  I am interested to learn more about this phenomena as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think not. faster charger actually put more energy into your battery (`1A = 1W * 1V^-1`). your battery's Voltage is at charging and discharging the same (or to be specific, it's rising while charging and dropping while discharging, but the same amount *), so basically the difference between the two chargers is the energy (A) which comes, and because of the same Voltage (V) the Power (W) must be different. if you discharge, the processor (and display,...) consumpts power (W), but the Voltage is still the same.

* what is **not** the same is how fast your battery would discharge in relation to the actual charging percentage (or, better known as slower charging at end of charging)